# Make answering notice for unregistered users be translatable via Traducir

Tags: feature-request, support, answers, localization, unregistered-users

On sites where answering for unregistered users is available, they will see the following notice below the post body text area:

> Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow!
>
> Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your
> research! But avoid …
>
> Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers. Making
> statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal
> experience. To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers.

> [image]

This block has translation (at least on ruSO and esSO):

> [image]

> [image]

But for some reason I'm [not able to find that string in traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=nks%20for%20contributin). It seems that that string is translated somewhere else. What's the reason for it? Could we just make it translatable via traducir? Current translation in Russian requires some fixes and it would be better to do that work without staff in future.